# geocoding data or possibly IP into a google map

Tags: php, sql, google-maps, real-time, geocode

I have a donations section on my website and I'm interested whether the following feature is possible: I have a donors portion of the site where I'd like to incorporate a Google map which has pins placed in all the locations that donations came from--these locations dont have to be exact (IP address would work fine I think).

I was wondering whether making a Google map that displays donation activity in real-time is possible. If it requires actual data (city, state) it's possible for me to gather that information, because the website is currently set-up in the following way: a user selects the amount they would like to donate, they click the paypal button, they submit their donation via paypal, get re-routed to a thank you page that asks for a name, city and state (this info is stored via mySQL). After the user provides this data and hits submit (on the thank you page), they are re-routed to the donors page... this is where i would like to have a google map with pins representing all the people who donated and the city where they are from. Also, because the data is loaded in a SQL db, would it be possible to load the map with all the pins based in this data, and still have it update with new data too (in real-time)? Finally, I'm using PHP--any conflicts with that?

If anyone can offer any pointers I'd be so thankful. I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to Google API, so I'm not sure of the capabilities. I also tried to look at their docs and forums, but did not find anything extremely helpful. I'm grateful for your time, and I thank you for any help!

Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geolocation of the user's browser can be retrieved using the W3C geolocation API. It's pretty in-depth so if you're not in for the reading I have included some prototype code I was playing with. It should show a marker with your current browser location.

http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

You can store the longitude and latitude information into your database and later parse it and insert the markers into google maps with javascript.

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize(location) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude,location.coords.longitude);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 19,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map, 
      title:"Hello World!"
  });   
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code; however, it's not exactly what I'm looking for, but it's a good start. I'm looking for code that only places people who have donated on a map, not necessarily ever user that accesses the donor page. I fear that this code places anyone on a map, while I'm trying to show only those who have donated. I suppose my initial question is the problem... not your response. So let me rephrase: Assuming that I have a city and a state data (via SQL), how do I pass that data to Google Maps so that it displays it on my site? Also can the Googlemap refresh every few seconds? Thank you

Comment: The code I have provided will allow you to fill in a field in the form when the user donates. This field will be automatically filled with the user's longitude and latitude, which can be stored in the database when the form is submitted.

You can use the javascript command setInterval() to issue an AJAX request for new donaters.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Use the Google Map Javascript API to add fresh placemarkers for new donators. (Add Overlay)
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#AddingOverlays